# How to infer frequency from an index where a few observations are missing?

Tags: python, pandas

Using [pd.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) like `dr = pd.date_range('2020', freq='15min', periods=n_obs)` will produce this DateTimeIndex with a 15 minute interval or frequency:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-01 00:15:00',
           '2020-01-01 00:30:00', '2020-01-01 00:45:00',
           '2020-01-01 01:00:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='15T')
```

You can use this to set up a pandas dataframe like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data
np.random.seed(10)
n_obs = 10
daterange = pd.date_range('2020', freq='15min', periods=n_obs)
values = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=n_obs).tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':daterange, 'value':values})
df = df.set_index('time')
```

And now you can use `pd.infer_freq(df.index)` to retreive the frequency `'15T'` again for further calculations. Taking a closer look at `help(pd.infer_freq())` lets us know that [pd.infer_freq](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.infer_freq.html) will:

> ```
> Infer the most likely frequency given the input index. If the frequency is
> uncertain, a warning will be printed.
> ```

My understanding of this would be that it would be possible to retrieve `'15T'` if a few observations were missing, leading to an irregular time index. But when I remove a few of the observations using:

```
dropped = df.index[[1,3]]
df =  df.drop(dropped)
```

Then `pd.infer_freq(df.index)` returns `None`. This also happens if we set `n_obs = 100`. So it would seem that I was hoping for a bit too much when I thought that `[...] infer the most likely frequency [...]` meant that `pd.infer_freq()` could infer that this was in fact an index with a 15 minute frequency with only a few missing values. Is there any other approach I could use to programmatically infer an index frequency from a somewhat irregular time series using pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could compute the minimum time difference of values in the index (here `min_delta`), try to find 3 consecutive values in the index, each with this minimum time difference between them, and then call `infer_freq` on these consecutive values of the index:

```py
diffs = (df.index[1:] - df.index[:-1])
min_delta = diffs.min()
mask = (diffs == min_delta)[:-1] & (diffs[:-1] == diffs[1:])
pos = np.where(mask)[0][0]
idx = df.index
print(pd.infer_freq(idx[pos: pos + 3]))
```

This retrieves "15T".